# xslt to rename nodes based on recursive position

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to travel through the nodes in my XHTML document, finding all the node children that match a set of criteria, and renaming them based on their position relative to how deep they are in the document hierarchy.

For example:

I want to iterate over the nodes in the  element, and transform all that are h1,h2,h3,h4,h5, or h6, into h1.

Then I want to iterate over all the other children of the  element, and find their child nodes, with a name of hN, and names these to h2.

And etc, up to unlimited depth of recursion through the child nodes, but naming elements up to a limit of h6...

is this clear? Pardon, I am new to xsl.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,'_col')]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="iterate"/>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="*" mode="iterate">

    <xsl:if test="name()='h1' or name()='h2'or name()='h3'or name()='h4'or name()='h5'or name()='h6'">
        <h6>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </h6>

    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="name()!='h1' and name()!='h2' and name()!='h3' and name()!='h4' and name()!='h5' and name()!='h6'">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously this won't work at all - leaving off the increment of the h# tag, if I can simply get the sheet to output the complete document with all the h# tags transormed to h1 tags, I'd feel pretty good. Can anyone help out?

thanks.

Edit:

First answer is a big help, but to be clear the problem is not just to increment all h# tags by one, up to six, it is to find all h# tags, then set those to an incremented number, up to six, depending on their depth in the doc hierarchy.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<h2>Theme</h2>
<div class="col _incidental">
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col _vital">
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h1>theme 3</h1>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h4>theme 3</h4>
        <p>some thext</p>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col _related">
      <h2>theme 2</h2>
      </div>   
          <div>
                <h5>theme 3</h5>
                <p>some thext</p>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the output ought to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<h1>Theme</h1>
<div class="col _incidental">
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col _vital">
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
        <h3>theme 3</h3>
        <p>some thext</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col _related">
    <h2>theme 2</h2>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>theme 3</h3>
            <p>some thext</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The transformation contains hN elements that are numbered according to their position in the doc hierarchy, relative to the last hN found. So if I find an h2, and then any siblings will be searched through, and any hN's become h3, and if none are found, then their siblings are searched through, and they become h3, then any hN descendant of siblings become h4... make any sense?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide: 1. A complete (but small) XML document, and 2. The exact wanted result from the transformation.

Comment: user1558945, this is still a very confusing question! Please, edit and provide a full explanation of the rule for renaming the `HN` elements.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[starts-with(name(), 'H')
  and
    substring(name(),2) > 1
  and
    not(substring(name(),2) > 5)
   ]">

   <xsl:element name="h{substring(name(),2)+1}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (no source XML document has been provided!):

```
<html>
 <head/>
 <H2> Some H2</H2>

 <div>
   <H3>Some H3</H3>
   <div>
     <H4>Some H4</H4>

     <div>
       <H5>Some H5</H5>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<html>
   <head/>
   <h3> Some H2</h3>
   <div>
      <h4>Some H3</h4>
      <div>
         <h5>Some H4</h5>
         <div>
            <h6>Some H5</h6>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Proper use of templates and match patterns.
3. Proper use of the standard XPath functions **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with)** and **[`substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)** .
4. Proper use of **[`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)** s (Attribute Value Templates).

Comment: beautiful, thank you so much. it works, although I'm going to have to read up on the "namespace::" as i have no idea what that means. there remains some tweaking to get my desired outcome - I am having to set the initial #, depending on some factors, as in: once the initial h# is determined, begin replacing with the next highest #, and increment again, up to 6, each time the template is called on any h# match - I think a with-param can do that well... but this is clearly a tremendous boost, so thanks!

Comment: Dimitre, I have added some xml, pre and post transformation. I would like to click the check, however there is one more complexity that I'm still not clear on: the solution you provided increments all the h#'s by one, but I need to first set the child nodes that are h# to a value, then find all the descendent nodes within the siblings, and set those to increment by whatever the first # was... is that clear?

Comment: @user1558945, No, this isn't clear -- this is why a good question provides a sample XML document and the exact wanted result. Could you, please, edit the question and provide the exact rules?

Comment: your answer is good, but I think it wasn't clear that the nodes need to be numbered in incremental h# based on their position in the hierarchy, not just incremented based on their current value. So an if I have an h2 and an h5 as siblings, they both need to be named, for example, h2, and any children of sibling nodes that are h# need to be h3, and etc. in your answer, I'd have an h3 and h6 as siblings... correct?

Comment: @user1558945, You must add to the question a full explanation of the ruls for renaming

Comment: I have expanded my explanation. Hope this helps. thanks!